# "Couldn't find story matching 'example-api--primary' after HMR" error in Storybook

Tags: javascript, svelte, storybook

I try to configure Storybook in Svelte project.

I want to create a section with only "Docs" tab.
But if I add in parameters "docs" section (no metter whats inside), I get a error:

```
Couldn't find story matching 'example-api--primary' after HMR.
- Did you remove it from your CSF file?
- Are you sure a story with that id exists?
- Please check your stories field of your main.js config.
- Also check the browser console and terminal for error messages.
```

In console:
`Unable to load story 'example-api--primary'`

almost all code bellow I take from StoryBook site.

My story file:
Api.stories.js

```
import Button from '../../stories/Button.stories';

export default {
  title: 'Example/API',
  component: Button,
parameters: {
    previewTabs: {
        canvas: { hidden: true},
    },
    viewMode: 'docs',
    docs: {
        page: ApiStories,
    },
    
  },
};

stories/introduction#using-args
const Template = (args) => ({
  Component: Button,
  props: args,  
});

export const Primary = Template.bind({});
Primary.args = {  
};
```

My ApiStories.mdx file:

```
<!-- Custom-MDX-Documentation.mdx -->



# Replacing DocsPage with custom `MDX` content

This file is a documentation-only `MDX`file to customize Storybook's [DocsPage](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-docs/docs-page#replacing-docspage).

It can be further expanded with your own code snippets and include specific information related to your stories.

For example:

import { Story } from "@storybook/addon-docs";

## Button

Button is the primary component. It has four possible states.

- [Primary](#primary)
- [Secondary](#secondary)
- [Large](#large)
- [Small](#small)

## With the story title defined

If you included the title in the story's default export, use this approach.

### Primary

<Story id="example-button--primary" />

### Secondary

<Story id="example-button--secondary" />

### Large

<Story id="example-button--large" />

### Small

<Story id="example-button--small" />

## Without the story title defined

If you didn't include the title in the story's default export, use this approach.

### Primary

<Story id="your-directory-button--primary"/>

### Secondary

<Story id="your-directory-button--secondary"/>

### Large

<Story id="your-directory-button--large"/>

### Small

<Story id="your-directory-button--small" />
```

My config file:
.storybook/main.js

```
module.exports = {
  "stories": [
    "../src/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx|svelte)"
  ],
  "addons": [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions"
  ],
  "framework": "@storybook/svelte",
  "svelteOptions": {
    "preprocess": require("svelte-preprocess")()
  }
}
```

How to add something in Docs tab correctly?